# Configure RAID with 6 drives on Dell PowerEdge 2850

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge

I'm trying to configure 6 146MB discs in 3 pairs of 2 as RAID 1 on my PowerEdge 2850 Server.

This is how far I get:

ONLIN A00-00
ONLIN A00-01

ONLIN A01-00
ONLIN A01-01

ONLIN A02-00
ONLIN A02-01

Span-1  Span-2  Span-3

From here, I can only configure 1 Logical Drive, and the BIOS only sees 1 drive. If I understand the tutorials correctly, I should be seeing something like this:

LD  RAID  Size      #Stripes
0    1    146xxxxx    2
1    1    146xxxxx    2
2    1    146xxxxx    2

Where 3 logical drives appear, because of the A00, A01, and A02 array's I created in the beginning. Please help me fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're actually in the RAID utility that comes up at boot time, right?

It sounds like your server is already configured with a single RAID 5 volume.  You'll need to get rid of the old volume and create a new one.  Go into Configuration and make your changes there.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDr1ok42JmA) might help you.